# Do I still need to use the kapt plugin (I am using ksp) if I am enabling dataBinding for a project?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kapt

I am aware that dataBinding requires an annotation processor (that is provided by kapt), is there anyway to use ksp for that purpose?

Answer (score 7):

As highlighted [here](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173030256#comment10), Google is phasing out dataBinding in favor of compose and KSP support for Data Binding is not planned. Therefore the use of kotlin-kapt plugin is still required.